# Windows 7 over Ubuntu without a CD Drive

Tags: windows-7

I am not that experienced in installing operation systems.
I bought a PC that has Ubuntu on it but I want to replace it with Windows 7.
I have been following all the steps that were covered in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CkVsorC3z4). 
But the problem is that once I open the archive manager it only contains a text file saying this

```
This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating system
that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification.
```

The main problem is that the laptop does not have a CD drive at all

Can you please give me any possible solutions or guides

Answer (score 0):

First make a backup of your flashdrive's files on another computer

Secondly download a Windows 7 ISO and Unebootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Using Unebootin create a bootable USB (make sure it's plugged in) with the Win7 ISO

Follow this tutorial if you have problems https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPZJ0oCQxu0